# Qt - How to insert item to tree view with Qt designer?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

[image]

Is it possible to insert some default items, like the `TCP Server` `TCP Client` `UDP Server/Client/Group` in the above picture,  to tree view with Qt designer ?

Comment: `QTreeView`? No. `QTreeWidget`? Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QT Designer, you can edit the contents of the tree widget through the "Edit Items" menu entry from the context menu which opens the "Edit Tree Widget" dialog:

[image]